# How to get LCID String form LCID in JavaSscript?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm developing for CRM 2011 and 2013, and I want to get the user's language. The only command I can execute is Xrm.Page.context.getUserLcid(), and it gives the language id, like 1033 for US English.
But, I want to have the LCID String, like 'en-US'.
Is there a way to get this, in JavaScript? Perhaps a default function in CRM?
And is there also a way to get all languages that are installed in CRM?

Answer (score 1):

I created a JavaScript library to handle your requirement (returns the culture name from a decimal lcid value)

The mapping comes from this page: [National Language Support (NLS) API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx) (Windows 7)

Practically inside the library there is JSON object with the values and two methods to get them.

You can find more information on my blog:

[LCID JavaScript Helper Library](http://www.crmanswers.net/2014/06/lcid-javascript-helper-library.html)

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of installed languages - recheck [this article](http://mileyja.blogspot.com/2011/08/retrieve-installed-language-packs-in.html)
Regarding conversion of Language Code -I believe you will need to write conversion function like:

```
function GetLocale(languagecode){
if (languagecode == 1033){
return "en-US";
}
else if (languagecode == 1064){
return "ua-UA";
}
else {
return "not found!";
}
}
```

Comment: So I have to add them all manually? There is no existing function? That's too bad..

Comment: I have never faced with scenario where I needed it so I don't know for sure. But if I'm not wrong - there is no such function. You will have to develop it.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Is there a function to get the format language (for example for prices) from CRM?

Comment: I mean the formatting of the prices: Whether you comma's ($3,00) or dots ($3.00), time: 3:45PM or 15.45 and things like that

Comment: I believe to get it you need to fetch usersettings entity for running user.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the language from the variable `USER_LANGUAGE_TWO_LETTER_NAME`, in CRM2016 at least, probably in older versions too.

From within a WebResource you need to make sure to go up to the top window first, e.g.:

```
    var root = window.parent;
    while (root.frameElement !== null) {
      root = root.parent;
    }
    var lang = root.USER_LANGUAGE_TWO_LETTER_NAME
```